# Pass strings between application and DLL with Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, dll, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe3

I need write a DLL and an application with Delphi (XE2 or XE3).
I need pass a paramenter with many strings from application to DLL then I need send many strings from DLL to application as result. Besides my DLL must be compatible also with C++ application if possible.

Somethings like this:

function(aInStrings: TStringList; out aOutStrings: TStringList): boolean;

I don't want use TStringList becasuse I know this is a problem with DLL.
Is there a fast way (without use ShareMem, FastMem, BORLNDMM.DLL, ...) to solve my problem?

Comment: Use WideString, aka BSTR. Put all the strings from the list into a single WideString. Use a delimiter, e.g. a linebreak or a \0. This works in both directions. Only don't use WideString as a finction return value since Delphi return values have different semantics from all the other compilers. Return using an out parameter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the strings may contain linebreak or other delimiters. Maybe use array of BSTR? and pass a pointer to that array specifying length for the in array, and returning out length for the out array?

Comment: @kobik You don't know that. Assuming that they don't contain line breaks then myWideStringVariable := Strings.Text, and vice versa, is all you need. Problem with your suggestion is who allocates and deallocates the out array. That's why BSTR is nice. Shared COM allocater sweeps that inconvenience out of sight.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, DLL should allocate out array with common memory allocator like LocalAlloc and caller should deallocate with LocalFree. and the shared COM allocater will take care of the BSTR elements.

Comment: @kobik faster would be to allocate buffer once on load and free it when no more used, or maybe to pass current AllocMem/FreeMem values to DLL. Providing application/DLL boundary is single-threaded and non-reenterable.

Comment: Usual Windows convention is passing PChar (acctually you should fix it would be either PAnsiChar  or PWideChar since in DLL you don't have type safety and need to fix all the details explicitly). Then at that pointer would be a set of C-strings ending with empty C-string as end marker, like `'ABCDE'#0'FGHIJ'#0'KLMNO'#0#0` This convention is frequently used along Windows API and DLL developers should be familiar with it. However drawbacks are also obvious: data copying, no empty strings, no 0-character in the middle

Comment: @David, since you already talk about *Shared COM allocator* then why bother with making 0-delimited buffer at all ? Just let author passes TStringList into/out from DLL. Rather natural choice when he needs a number of strings. http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/AxCtrls_TStringsAdapter.html

Comment: @Arioch Because the DLL needs to be accessible using compilers other than the one used to build the DLL.

Comment: @David did you click the link ? Do you understand why i mentioned COM, not VCL? *For the record, i am against DLLs in Delphi only environment, though i admit BPL exposes much more API than they should.*

Comment: @Arioch You must not pass TStrings, which is what you wrote. You meant to write IStrings.

Comment: I meant the term that is instantly understandable by any programmer. I gave link for the wrapper but that is details "how to pass". Like when you talked about strings you did not mean "string" keyword but any structure to represent string.

Comment: @Arioch Oh come on! TStringList means a very specific thing. String is a very general term that encompasses many different language strings, C strings, BSTR etc. You meant IStrings. Which is in fact a good idea.

Comment: This is surely a repeated question, I believe I had such a question closed long ago for being an exact duplicate - of this one...

Comment: In this moment I use WideString and delimiter to pass a "single" string. I thought there was a better way...